# Cast object array to generic array

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, typecasting-operator

Currently, I am viewing the source code of java.util.ArrayList. Now I find the function **public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)** casts an object array to a generic array, just like code below:

```
 E[] newData = (E[]) new Object[Math.max(current * 2, minCapacity)];
```

However, when I declare the array to a specific type, IDE will show an error.

```
Object[] arr = new Object[10];
    int[] arr1 = (int[]) new Object[arr.length];
```

Any one is able to tell me the differences between them? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `E` (in the source code of `ArrayList`) stands for some *reference* type, but not for some *primitive* type.

And that's why you get a compile-time error when trying to cast an array of `Object` instances to an array of primitives.

If you do (for example)

```
Object[] arr = new Object[10];
Integer[] arr1 = (Integer[]) new Object[arr.length];
```

the error will be gone.

Answer (score 3):

You can never cast a reference type (anything that extends from `Object`) to a primitive type (`int`, `long`, `boolean`, `char`, etc.).

You can also not cast an array of a reference type like `Object[]` to an array of a primitive type like `int[]`.

And primitives cannot stand in for a generic parameter.

Comment: One exception though: auto-boxing, e.g. boxing a primitive `int` into an `Integer` object. But you're correct about array casts: even with auto-boxing, you cannot cast an `int[]` into an `Integer[]`.

Comment: @MattiasBeulens But that's not casting. That's simply wrapping the value

Comment: @VinceEmigh Technically correct, but it looks like a cast so I thought I'd at least mention it.

Answer (score 2):

`int` is not `Object`, but it's primitive.

Use `Integer` and it will work.

```
Object[] arr = new Object[10];
    Integer[] arr1 = (Integer[]) new Object[arr.length];
```